Java NIO DatagramChannel: Unable to Open Multiple Sockets on Same Port with IPv4 and IPv6
Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm encountering an issue while working on a project involving Java NIO Datagram Channels. My goal is to open two sockets on the same port, one using IPv4 and the other using IPv6. However, every time I attempt to do so, I encounter the error message "port already in use" when trying to open the second socket. Interestingly, if one socket is opened with IPv4, attempting to open the second socket with IPv6 triggers the above-mentioned error, and vice versa.
Here's a snippet of the relevant code:
// Opening IPv4 socket
DatagramChannel ipv4Channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET);
ipv4Channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

// Opening IPv6 socket
DatagramChannel ipv6Channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET6);
ipv6Channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

Is there a specific configuration i need to set to allow opening multiple sockets on the same port, each with different IP versions, using Java NIO DatagramChannels?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've ensured that the port I'm attempting to bind to is available and not in use by any other process.

@Slaw is their any other alternative similar to IPV6_only option which is present for BSD sockets ? I wanted to avoid using REUSEADDR .

Hi @Slaw, it is not the case of 'reuse', one should be allowed to open a socket on same port if source ip address, transport protocol etc are different. The 'reuse' should come into play when they are all same. In this case, the IP Address would be different for IPv4 (INADDR_ANY) and IPv6 (INADDR_ANY6).

@AbhishekJain Ah yes, you're right. And using 127.0.0.1 and ::1 with the same port works for me. However, it doesn't seem to work with 0.0.0.0 and ::.

Yes that’s the problem. Why this problem with NIO channels? When normally it works say using BSD socket APIs.
