Configuring Java NIO Channels for IPv4 and IPv6 Separately
I've been looking into Java NIO channels for a project, specifically aiming to open sockets for both IPv4 and IPv6 configurations separately. While DatagramChannel provides an option to specify the IP family via its open method, I've encountered a limitation where I cannot open another socket with a different IP family on the same port given a socket is already opened for a different family on the same port.
Although I've posted a related question about this issue, I'm also curious if there's a way to specify IP family when using ServerSocketChannel or SocketChannel. I've searched extensively but couldn't find any open variants that can accommodate specifying the IP family.
Here's a snippet of the approach I've attempted with DatagramChannel:
// Attempting to open sockets for IPv4 and IPv6 separately
DatagramChannel ipv4Channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET);
ipv4Channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

DatagramChannel ipv6Channel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET6);
ipv6Channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port)); // Throws "port already in use" error


Is there a method or technique available to achieve this configuration separation with ServerSocketChannel or SocketChannel? Your insights and guidance would be immensely helpful.
Thank you in advance!
I tried looking into documentation and see if I could find a sample project for my use-case but no luck so far.

The related question mentioned by the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78537127/6395627

They don't appear to be available in Android, but the SocketChannel#open(ProtocolFamily) and ServerSocketChannel#open(ProtocolFamily) methods were added in Java 15.

Thanks @Slaw,  Soo i can't specify any ip family when opening the sockets, does that mean when i open a socket on say port "X", it will listen for both ipv4 and ipv6 traffic provided it is enabled.
